# Laravel SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm working on a Laravel application for a while now, but when I run  `php artisan migrate` now, all out of a sudden I always get the error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `migrations` (`migration`, `batch`) values (2019_06_05_080701_create_departments_table, 22))
```

and I have no clue why this happens since thsi never happened before. When I try to migrate a specific migration I get the same error, so what is going on here?

The migration looks like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('departments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('company_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('p_number')->nullable();
        $table->string('address')->nullable();
        $table->string('zipcode')->nullable();
        $table->string('city')->nullable();
        $table->string('contact_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('contact_email')->nullable();
        $table->string('contact_phone')->nullable();

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Result of `SHOW COLUMNS FROM migrations;`

[image]

Comment: Have you created a migrations table on your own?

Comment: Please show us the code for that migration.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson please check my updated question :-) Anyhow, it is on every migration...

Comment: @DrakulaPredator No and thats the weird part...

Comment: Agree with @DrakulaPredator. @ST80 can you show result of [`SHOW COLUMNS FROM migrations;`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html)?

Comment: @marv255 Please check my updated question...

Comment: Can you fire `EXPLAIN migrations` and see if it set to autoincrement or not

Comment: This problem caused if you upgrade laravel from 5.2 to current version, So for workaround solution edit id column in migration table and set it "auto increment"

Comment: YOu are missing auto increment in migrations table

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fire this query should work for autoincrement, that's the reason value of id is not getting auto incrementing

```
ALTER TABLE migrations MODIFY id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

> **Note:** If there are ids with 0 then you should change it to some other
>   unique id value, and later get the max value of id by query and set
>   autoincrement to +1

```
SET @new_index = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM migrations );
SET @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE migrations AUTO_INCREMENT = ', @new_index);
PREPARE st FROM @sql;
EXECUTE st;
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24439266/11608095).

Comment: I get the error: `1062 - ALTER TABLE causes auto_increment resequencing, resulting in duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Comment: You can get help with this specific problem from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402949/mysql-cant-make-column-auto-increment). But I am sure your problem is with autoincrement.

Comment: have you checked if id column has 0 values?

Comment: Hmm yes, the first entry has id = 0

Comment: @ST80 Once check my answer now

Comment: @ST80 Does My changes helped you solve your problem?

Comment: Yeah, your answer is similiar with the one I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402949/mysql-cant-make-column-auto-increment) . So I'm gonna accept it .-)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research and good answers I found this solution, which solved it for me:

```
ALTER TABLE migrations CHANGE COLUMN `id` `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT = 123456;
```

The solution is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402949/mysql-cant-make-column-auto-increment) answer from a similiar question- Thanks to [@Dracula Predator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11608095/drakula-predator-%D9%85) for the good hint.

Answer (score 0):

You have been getting this error because probably you have modified migrations table. 
You can try few options

1. Run php artisan migrate:fresh command
2. Drop all tables and rerun all migration

Comment: As you can read in the question the error throws during inserting something into the migrations table which (normally and in this case) is not affected by migration scripts. So your solution is not usefull.